# Click is not emitted when sending element to foreground

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While creating a simple diagramming component I cannot combine correctly the dragging, sending dragged element to foreground and clicking.

What I would like to achieve:

1. The dragged or clicked element should be sent to foreground (in front of other elements)
2. The select action should not be emitted for dragged element
3. Tap or click should select an element

It works well for the element that is in front of other elements, but clicking on any other elements just sends it to front, without clicking. Could you please help me with that?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1o1dnpsw/2/

**HTML**

```
<svg width="250" height="150">
</svg>
<div id="msg">click on rectangle or drag it</div>
<p>Problem: while clicking on the element which is not on the foreground (yellow) the click is not emitted.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
body { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; } 
svg { border: 1px solid gray; }
svg rect { border: 1px solid gray; }
div { border: 1px dotted gray; margin-top: 10px; width: 250px; height: 25px;
  text-align: center; line-height: 25px; }
```

**script**

```
function select() {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerText =
        'selected at ' + new Date().getTime();
}

function addBox(color, x, y) {
    var r = d3.selectAll('svg').append('rect')
        .attr('x', x).attr('y', y)
        .attr('width', 50).attr('height', 50)
        .attr('fill', color)
        .on('mousedown', function () {
            // move element to foreground
            this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
        })
        .on('click', function () {
            // do not click when dragged
            if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
                return;
            }
            select();
        })
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function () { return { x : x, y : y }; })
            .on('dragstart', function () {
                d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
            })
            .on('drag', function () {
                x = d3.event.x;
                r.attr('x', x);
                y = d3.event.y;
                r.attr('y', y);
            })
            .on('dragend', function () {
            }));
}

addBox('#FFC60D', 10, 10);
addBox('#161EFF', 40, 40);
```

Comment: Just on a side note: The click event doesn't work at all in Firefox. Chrome fine though.

Comment: Last note before I go to bed: Change innerText() to textContent() will fix it for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1o1dnpsw/3/

Added 2 variables to function addBox():

```
var oldX;
var oldY;
```

And changed both the drag and dragend events to:

```
.on('drag', function () {
    oldX = r.attr('x');
    oldY = r.attr('y');
    x = d3.event.x;
    r.attr('x', x);
    y = d3.event.y;
    r.attr('y', y);
})
.on('dragend', function () {
    if (x == oldX && y == oldY) {
        select();
    }
}));
```

Comment: Basicly what it does is check if you actually dragged it around or not. If not it'll fire up the select() event.